# smoothness of the group action $GL(n+1,\Bbb{R})$ on $RP^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I was trying to show that the group action $GL(n+1,\Bbb{R})$ on $RP^n$ which is defined as $A[x] = [Ax]$ is a smooth transitive action.

The transitivity of this action is obvious since $GL(n+1,\Bbb{R})$ acts on $\Bbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ is smooth transitive action.Only need to check the smoothness of the action,one idea is to compute the map under coordinate. It seems a bit complicated to write it down,so I came another idea, the action on $RP^n$ seems to be the induced action on $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ ,which is easy to check it's smooth, so is there some universal property that guarantees that the action on $RP^n$ is also smooth ?

the diagram looks as follows:
[here](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNCxbMCwwLCJHTChuKzEsXFxCYmJ7Un0pXFx0aW1lcyBcXEJiYntSfV57bisxfVxcc2V0bWludXMgXFx7MFxcfSJdLFswLDEsIlxcUl57bisxfVxcc2V0bWludXMgXFx7MFxcfSJdLFsxLDEsIlJQXm4iXSxbMSwwLCJHTChuKzEsXFxSKVxcdGltZXMgUlBebiJdLFswLDFdLFsxLDJdLFszLDJdLFswLDNdXQ==)

Comment: Presumably you want the standard coordinate action of $GL(n+1, \mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, which descends to an action on $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

Comment: Yeah ,this action seems natural ,maybe there is some universal property about the smooth group action ?

Comment: Well your Group action is the composition of the group action on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus 0$ and the projection map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to RP^n$

Comment: @yili You shoul edit your question to correct dimension.

Comment: Oh I find it's just universal property of surjective submersion

Comment: @yili Then you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commutative diagram of the group action is shown as follows:

[image]

where $\rho_1$ is the natural action of $GL$ on $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$,
We can show that $\pi$ is smooth surjective submersion,so it's the map $id \times \pi$. what we know is $\pi \circ \rho_1$ is smooth ,by universal property of surjective smooth submersion $\rho_2$ is smooth if and only if $\pi\circ \rho_1$ is smooth.

For what is characteristic property of surjective submersion see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/119732/97016)